# Is it safe to update the Dictionary from multiple threads with the same key/value

Tags: .net, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a static `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K, V>` that's used as a cache. On a cache miss I do some expensive work to get the value for the specified key and save it in the cache:

```
private static Dictionary<K, V> _cache = ...

public static V GetValue<K>(K key)
{
    V value;
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
         value = GetExpensiveValue(key);
         _cache[key] = value; // Thread-safety issue?
    }

    return value;
}
```

This is a common pattern. The question is: is this safe or could it fail when multiple threads try to call `GetValue()` at the same time?

Assuming that `GetExpensiveValue` always returns the same value for a given key, I don't really care which thread wins the race condition. Yes, it means that the expensive operation is potentially done one more time than needed, but that's a trade-off I may be happy with if reads are far more frequent than writes and this allows me to eliminate locking. But would something actually go wrong inside the Dictionary? That is, would it throw an exception or corrupt its data in some cases? I tested this out with a simple console app and found no issues, but of course that doesn't mean it will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look thread-safe to me; the inside of the dictionary could already be in the process of being re-written. At a *minimum* it probably needs a reader/writer lock:

```
private readonly static ReaderWriterLockSlim @lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
public static V GetValue(K key)
{
    V value;
    @lock.EnterReadLock();
    bool hasValue;
    try
    {
        hasValue = _cache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    finally
    {
        @lock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    if (!hasValue)
    {
        value = GetExpensiveValue(key);
        @lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _cache[key] = value;
        }
        finally
        {
            @lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

and if you only want `GetExpensiveValue(key)` to execute once, move it *inside* the write-lock and add a double-check:

```
        @lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            if(!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value)) { // double-check
                value = GetExpensiveValue(key);
                _cache[key] = value;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            @lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about race conditions then you should be fine. If you care about the expensive operation, just `lock` after `TryGetvalue()` and then call `TryGetValue()` again

```
private static Dictionary<K, V> _cache = ...
private static object _lockObject = new object();

public static V GetValue<K>(K key)
{
    V value;
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                 value = GetExpensiveValue(key);
                 _cache[key] = value; // Thread-safety issue?
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

**Edit:**
After consideration of Marc's comment, I think the above is not the best option. Perhaps consider using the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.

Comment: That is not safe; TryGetValue *itself* is not thread-safe, and could explode in a shower of sparks if the dictionary is being mutated by another thread

Comment: Good point Marc. Perhaps it'd be better to just go with a System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<>()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx